# Control Custom Post Type template from a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I can control the custom template to be used on custom post type pages but the template file would still need to have the markup of the theme. I was wondering if I could make it theme independent?

Example: I have a plugin that registers my custom post type. I have the post meta info that I want to show in a custom template. I have that template working on my custom post type pages but the max I could do is to use get_header() & get_footer() calls but I can't deal out the need of having the theme markup between header & footer.

Did that make any sense? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got it working by the following code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ft_job_cpt_template' );

function ft_job_cpt_template() {
    global $wp, $wp_query;

    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && $wp->query_vars['post_type'] == 'job' ) {
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            add_filter( 'the_content', 'ft_job_cpt_template_filter' );
        }
        else {
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }
    }
}

function ft_job_cpt_template_filter( $content ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $jobID = $wp_query->post->ID;

    $output = ''; // Build markup fetching info from postmeta

    return $output;
}
```

Feel free to comment on any suggestions.

Comment: Why not just hook onto `the_content` and check the post type there? - just a bit cleaner :)

Comment: @StephenHarris Kicking in the filter only when needed makes more sense to me here, and I find this a lot cleaner. Consider if you have lot of stuff going on, it would be better to just have a function which kicks in or kicks out certain things all from one place. And this also makes sure if a certain content is processed a large no of times, it doesn't go under the filter call just to check if it should do anything or not. A bit of performance gain too. And you can reuse filters in a better way this way, because filter just filters, and not judge conditions :)

Comment: Pretty cool so where is the template actually exist? Or is it all to be built in $output = '';

Comment: @willow Use `locate_template()` and `load_template()`, Here is a code sample on how you can do that - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template